# linux boot stick being ignored on windows 7

Tags: linux, centos, windows, dual-boot

I am trying to install CentOS server on a machine that also runs Windows 7.  Towards this end:

```
1.) I created a 100GB "Unallocated" partition using the Disk Management tool in windows 7.  
2.) I then downloaded Universal USB Installer from this link http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/
3.) I used the installer to creat a USB stick with the CentOS iso file.
4.) I turned off my computer
5.) Inserted the USB stick into the usb drive
6.) Then started the computer.
```

But Windows launched instead of giving me a prompt to install Linux.  I know the computer read the usb drive because the light on the usb drive went on before windows launched.  **What am I missing?**

Comment: You need to tell your computer to boot from the USB stick of course.  How to do that varies from motherboard to motherboard but it usually involves pressing F11 or delete during boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use This tool Instead: [LinuxLiveCreator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/).  I've Found it to be more reliable.  After doing so, reboot.  If you still receive Windows7, you need to change the boot order in your BIOS to include USB devices.

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to mark this as accepted.  Thank you and +1.  The actual solution was to change the boot order in the BIOS.  I did use the tool you suggested, but I don't think the tool was the problem.